# onblur event not working on <input> element

Tags: javascript, forms, onblur

I have a field on a form that is hidden but pulls data from another field to fill it in. Yet when I have tried it it does not work. I need to use `class` not `id` to fill the field.

**Field with onblur Event**

```
 <input name="EmailAddress" type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="EmailAddress" 
       onblur="document.getElementByClass('Username2').value=this.value;" 
       maxlength="255" />
```

**Field That Is Being Filled**

```
 <input type="text" class="Username2" id="Username" name="Username" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `.getElementByClass()` as far as I know; it's `.getElementsByClassName()` (note: element*S* is plural, since it can return more than one). When using it to get one element, you need to add its array index at the end (`[0]`).

Try:

```
<input name="EmailAddress" type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="EmailAddress" 
   onblur="document.getElementsByClassName('Username2')[0].value=this.value;" 
   maxlength="255" />
<input type="text" class="Username2" id="Username" name="Username" />
```